# problem when refreshing the page at pagination using query string and react context

Tags: reactjs, pagination, query-string, react-bootstrap, react-context

I've build a pagination using react bootstrap. Everything works fine except when i refresh the page while i'm at page, let's say 3, the app refreshes and goes to page 1.
I've tried using react context but the page parameter had problems with other context parameters because i am using useEffect on them.

Comment: When you hit refresh, all the state surely will be reset. Why do you need to refresh?

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh a page, everything starts all over again from the beginning by default.

If you want to keep your state, there's typically two solutions :

- store a part of your state in the url
- store a part of your state in the localStorage

Then, on first load, try to retreive values from url or localStorage and put them in initial state values.